# ASP.NET Core 5 Identity redirects to http instead of https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-identity

I hope I'm just overlooking something small.

But my issue is that I used the following code snippet in the `Startup.cs`-file to force redirections to the login page of my webapp, when there's no user signed in.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
});
```

My problem now is, that whenever a redirection is done by Microsoft Identity (no matter if login or logout) one will get redirected to a non safe http site.

I am using a Nginx reverse proxy with a Let's encrypt SSL-certificate, so the webapp is actually running on http. Is there a possibility to solve my issue?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Is nginx setting `X-Forwarded-Proto` correctly? `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

Comment: @abdusco {services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });} 
This is what also is in my Startup.cs file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Have you also got `app.UseForwardedHeaders();` in the `Configure` method?

Comment: @DavidG yes, I do. Still doesn't work...

Comment: There are two possible reasons: nginx does not set headers correctly or your app doesn't read those headers correctly. I solved it by creating a test page that simply dumps all headers so I could confirm nginx sends correct requests. This way I had the full request data and could continue on my local system using postman. S.a. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @ChristophLütjen big thanks to you. That was the right hint!

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I've got another problem now. Maybe you could help. When I try to use Microsoft Identity the redirect URI provided by my app is an http URL. Therefore it doesn't work. Do you know a solution?

Comment: I don't remember the details, I checked my startup and it looks like this `services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => {              options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;  options.KnownProxies.Clear();        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();  });` and `app.UseForwardedHeaders();` - that's what works for me. So nginx should send `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` and the app should respect this with `ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto`.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Big cheers to you!